# Docker and Golang permission denied : "can't create log directory"

Tags: docker, go, permissions, file-permissions, user-permissions

Hello,
I'm here today because I'm stuck on a permission problem of my application.
I have set up a "lumberjack" log system to keep track of everything that happens on my application and rotate logs. In local I don't have any problem... but when I go in production it's not the same.

My error appear here when I want to access at "/var/log/app:

```
if err := os.MkdirAll(config.Directory, 0755); err != nil {
    log.Error().Err(err).Str("path", config.Directory).Msg("can't create log directory")
    return nil
}
```

A part of my docker-compose.yml:
(maybe missing a volumes in this container ?)

```
app:
    container_name: app
    image: app
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - app
      - web
    environment:
      - xxx_USERNAME=xxxxx
      - xxx_PASSWORD=xxxxx
      - xxx_HOST=xxxxx
      - xxx_NAME=xxxxx
      - xxx_DEBUG=1
      - xxx_CONSOLELOGGING_LOG=TRUE
      - xxx_ENCODELOGJSON_LOG=TRUE
      - xxx_FILELOGGING_LOG=FALSE
      - xxx_DIRECTORY_LOG=/var/log/app
      - xxx_FILENAME_LOG=file.log
      - xxx_MAXSIZE_LOG=100
      - xxx_MAXBACKUPS_LOG=5
      - xxx_MAXAGE_LOG=30
    ports:
      - 443:443
    labels:
      - #TRAEFIK CONFIG
```

Makebuild for Docker:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags "-X main.gitCommit=$(GIT_COMMIT) -X main.buildDate=$(BUILD_DATE) -X main.version=$(VERSION) -linkmode external -extldflags '-static' -s -w" -a -installsuffix cgo -o web
```

Dockerfile for my production app:

```
############################
# STEP 1 build executable binary
############################
FROM golang:alpine as builder
# Install git + SSL ca certificates.
# Ca-certificates is required to call HTTPS endpoints.
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git ca-certificates gcc g++ make && update-ca-certificates
# Create appuser
RUN adduser -D -g '' appuser
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN go mod download
RUN go mod verify
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/cmd/web
#  Build the binary static link
RUN make docker
############################
# STEP 2 build a small image
############################
FROM scratch
WORKDIR /
# Import from builder.
COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
COPY --from=builder /etc/passwd /etc/passwd
# Copy our static executable and resources
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/cmd/web/web /web
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/cmd/web/views /views
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/cmd/web/static /static
# Use an unprivileged user.
USER appuser
ENTRYPOINT ["./web"]
CMD [":443"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you forgot to map volume to `/var/log/` ?

```
app:
    container_name: app
    image: app
    restart: always
    depends_on:
    - postgres
    networks:
    - app
    - web
    environment:
    - xxx_USERNAME=xxxxx
    - xxx_PASSWORD=xxxxx
    - xxx_HOST=xxxxx
    - xxx_NAME=xxxxx
    - xxx_DEBUG=1
    - xxx_CONSOLELOGGING_LOG=TRUE
    - xxx_ENCODELOGJSON_LOG=TRUE
    - xxx_FILELOGGING_LOG=FALSE
    - xxx_DIRECTORY_LOG=/var/log/app
    - xxx_FILENAME_LOG=file.log
    - xxx_MAXSIZE_LOG=100
    - xxx_MAXBACKUPS_LOG=5
    - xxx_MAXAGE_LOG=30
    ports:
    - 443:443
    labels:
    - #TRAEFIK CONFIG
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/log/
```

See the last line of docker compose snippet...

`FROM scratch` is empty... and you not creating new directory it with provided instructions. Add settings to map directory to your container.

Comment: don't work .. i try it yesterday
permission denied","path":"/var/log/app","time":"2021-08-04T09:11:42Z","message":"can't create log directory"}

Comment: Cosnider debuging yuor application: it means adding proper error message, env you running on (do you run with docker swarm?), running it with the privileged user and unprivileged (as you have now), ensuring that path exists, etc.